# Simultaneous changes in C++ for-loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 7; j > 3; j--){
            cout << array[i];
            cout << array[j];
        }
    }
```

Here, the value of `j` is changed for four times first, and then the program starts to change the value of `i`. 
Edit: Let's say, the array contains numbers that are relevant to their places: array[0] = 0, array[1] = 1 and so on. This method creates the following sequence: 0 7 0 6 0 5 0 4 1 7 ... Instead of this, I would like to have 0 7 1 6 2 5 ...
How do I make them change simultaneously?

Comment: Please share an input/output example.

Comment: Can you give an example of the `i` and `j` values for each iteration?

Comment: There happens to be a fairly simple way to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper, and write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write entire programs for other people, here, but always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
for ( int i = 0, n = 3, m = 4; i < 4; i++ )
{
    cout << array[n - i];
    cout << array[m + i];
}
```

Edit: After you changed the code in the question the following way

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 7; j > 3; j--){
            cout << array[i];
            cout << array[j];
        }
    }
```

then the loop can look

```
for ( int i = 0, n = 7; i < 4; i++ )
{
    cout << array[i];
    cout << array[n - i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example:

```
int j = 4;
for (int i = 3; i > -1; i--) {
    cout << array[i];
    cout << array[j];
    j++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the offset from the end, inside the array, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  cout << array[i] + array[7 - i];
```